# Sending files from client (angular) to server Asp.net wed api, request always has empty prorerty "files"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

everyone, have a trouble with sending files

I have angularjs client:

```
var fd = new FormData();

  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#someId' ) );
  fd.append('file', myEl[0].files[0]);
  fd.append('test', 'value');

               var vv = $resource('api/:domen/:url', { url: "", domen: 'Options' }, {

                'saveF': {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token,
                        'Content-Type': false
                    },
                    method: 'POST'
                }
            });



            vv.saveF({ url: "UploadData", domen: 'Info' }, fd, function (el) {

                console.log(el);

            });
```

The client code send fields, I can check it via Fiddler, the file is in body

and backend code on ASP.NET Web Api:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadData()
        {

           // var a = HttpContext.Current.Request;

          //  var f = a.Files.Get(0);


            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
              throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
            {
                var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

and so on

The request always fails, because of "Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()" or var f = a.Files.Get(0);
and I cannot get the file, server never see a content in request, but can see content-length

Already try to white content type 'multipart/form-data' but id didn`t help

Please, if somebody knows how to fix it - answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See back-end implementation of Web API 2: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

Also, you can use **ng-file-upload** for AngularJS

And example: https://github.com/stewartm83/angular-fileupload-sample

If you upload unknown MIME type and host your application on IIS, 
it would be good add MIME type to IIS.